# DataTable pagination not working with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I have no problem when displaying records using datatable. The problem is when I click the next/previous button, it will route to 404 Page Not Found. 
My js code:

```
$.ajax({
        url     : "position/load_position",
        method  : "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success : function (data) {
            $('#position_list').html(data);
            $('#position_data').dataTable( );
        }, 
    });
```

My php code:

```
public function load_position()
{
    $position  = $this->position_model->fetch_position();
    $output = '';

    $output .= '
        <div class="table-responsive table-responsive-data2">
            <table id="position_data" class="table " cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead class="  ">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th> 
                        <th>position</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
    ';

    if ($position->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($position->result_array() as $row) {
            $output .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>' . $row['position_id'] . '</td> 
                        <td>' . ucfirst($row['position']) . '</td>
                        <td><a title="Edit" href="#" class=" text-warning h5"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="#" title="Delete" class="text-danger h5 delete_position"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                    </tr> 
            ';
        }
    } 

    $output .= '
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    ';

    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

[Clicking the pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmq3Z.png)

[route to 404 Page not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVPds.png)

Comment: because it passes `undefined` in URL, solve that and it may work if no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

check ajax url

```
 $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/controllerName/FunctionName"
  });
```